# Display a line at grids background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

How can I store and display a line at the background of a grid container?
I had to set the background per resource dictionary.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!--here I had to display a vertical line at bottom,
                which goes over the whole window -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

or:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- here I had to display a vertical line at bottom,
                 which goes over the whole window and set the background color-->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that I need the red footer in each window of the application. I use a `ResourceDictionary` for styling. I can't use a picture, because I have to set the colors at runtime/for each application.

Comment: Can you show some XAML and explain a little more what you are trying to do? Where do you want this line? Vertical? Horizontal? One line? Many lines? Aligned to the grid somehow?

Comment: i has one grid, that override the standard style of my grid.
the problem is, that i had to set a color to the whole background of each application of the window, and draw a vertical line, which is set at bottom and has the width of the window

for my code, see my post... i have edit it

Comment: is there maybe a option to set the background of the window to a 
color and at the line too?
the idea with the grid is not a good idea, i think^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the brush itselft.

with the visualbrush you can draw anything as brush: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx

just do something like that

```
<VisualBrush>
...
<Grid Background="Red" .../>
<Line ... />

</VisualBrush>
```

Comment: that is, how i can i use it at the xaml of a window.... i meen, i can't use this at a seperate resourcedictionary