# Convert ListBoxItem to Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox, whose ItemsSource is binding. Is there anyway to convert each individual listbox item to an image of what is seen on the screen at runtime?

EDIT:

I have this right now, it doesn't seem to be working though...

```
ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        item = (ListBoxItem)(lb1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0));

        //itempres = item.Content as ItemsPresenter;

        //double width = itempres.ActualWidth;
        //double height = itempres.ActualHeight;
        double width = item.Width;
        double height = item.Height;

        //RenderTargetBitmap bmpCopied = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Round(width), (int)Math.Round(height), 100, 100, PixelFormats.Default);
        RenderTargetBitmap bmpCopied = new RenderTargetBitmap(100, 500, 100, 100, PixelFormats.Default);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(item);
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(width, height)));
        }
        bmpCopied.Render(drawingVisual);

        displayImage = new Image();
        displayImage.Source = bmpCopied;

        fd.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(displayImage));
            //ListBox lbNew = new ListBox();
            //lbNew.Style = lb1.Style;
            //lbNew.ItemsSource = lb1.ItemsSource;
            //lbNew.ItemContainerStyle = lb1.ItemContainerStyle;
            //lbNew.ItemTemplateSelector = lb1.ItemTemplateSelector;
            //UIElement elementAll = lbNew as UIElement;
            //fd.Blocks.Clear();
            //fd.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(elementAll));
        //}

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            fd.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
            fd.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
            fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(96);

            IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = fd;
            pd.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator, "flow doc");
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do a little more? Do you want your listbox items to be images, or do you just want to convert the listbox items, as they appear, into images, kinda like a screen cap?

Comment: what is bound? an ObservableCollection of path to images?

Comment: I want to convert the listbox items as they appear into images, like a screen capture.  The Listbox is bound to an observable collection of a type that I created.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working fine for me, i didn't try to print the image since i don't have a printer right now, but the image is correctly rendered in the test app i created

```
var listBoxItem = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)listBoxItem.ActualWidth,
                                                                           (int)listBoxItem.ActualHeight, 96, 96,
                                                                           PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderTargetBitmap.Render(listBoxItem);
            image.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
            image.Width = listBoxItem.ActualWidth;
            image.Height = listBoxItem.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I tried just the part you posted and the worked :D!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: One more question, if you could...when I throw this in a loop only the first image seems to be rendering...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered it a minute before: [Display a line at grids background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903063/display-a-line-at-grids-background/11903172#11903172)

Use the Visualbrush to create a brush and after that simply create a Drawingcontext and the draw a rectangle as example with your Visualbrush

Comment: Please see my code above.  Is that similar to what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment - so to augment Dtex's answer:

ListBoxItems just seem to act strangely for RenderTargetBitmap.
I was able to work around the issue by rendering the immediate child of the ListBoxItem itself like so:

```
var itemChildVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBoxItem,0) as Visual;
renderTargetBitmap.Render(itemChildVisual);
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Hope this helps!